# How to add additional variable columns for negated variables to generated truth table

Tags: list-manipulation, logic

I am creating truth table for $ p\Rightarrow !q $ with:

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{p, q, p \[Implies] ! q}, {p, q}], TableHeadings -> {None, {p, q, p \[Implies] ! q}}]
```

Truth table looks like:

```
p        q         p->!q
True    True    False
True    False   True
False   True    True
False   False   True
```

*"->" in table above and below actually looks like "$\Rightarrow$".  This because I cannot use latex for implication in the code segment.*

I want to generate a table for $ p\Rightarrow !q $ logic statement (and also to be able to do same with other logic statemens) so, that it also shows aditional columns for negated variables that are negated in a statement. For $ p\Rightarrow !q $ generated table should look like:

```
p        q         !q        p->!q
True    True    False   False
True    False   True    True
False   True    False   True
False   False   True    True
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @kglr Thank you. That is what I needed to do. I also understand how to include additional columns for other statements. If you want you can answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the additional column `!q`:

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{p, q, ! q, Implies[p, ! q]}, {p, q}], 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {p, q, ! q, Implies[p, ! q]}}] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{cccc}
>  p & q & \neg q & p\Rightarrow \neg q \\
>  \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
>  \text{True} & \text{False} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
>  \text{False} & \text{True} & \text{False} & \text{True} \\
>  \text{False} & \text{False} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}$